# fragment communications listener

Tags: android, android-fragments, communication

I got three fragments that uses all three the same list.

I want to make it so that whenever the list changes, it will push the changes to the fragments.

I would think that this would be done, from in the activity (interface) to the three fragments(or the ones that listenss in) implementing the interfaces inside the fragments.

Is this not the correct way?

Comment: what you are proposing seems like a reasonable first design attempt to me. What are you really asking?

Comment: Well im searching all over the place, but i only see fragments to activity to fragments communication. so im asking if this is still correct as im trying to do it like: activity to fragmentS .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your activity can hold references to the fragments it is showing, it would be fine to just include some methods for passing your updated list to the client fragments like:

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {

   private MyFragment fragment;

   //instantiate and show fragment at the correct time, save a reference to fragment

   public void onDataUpdate(List<Stuff> list) {
      fragment.updateList(list);
   }
}
```

you can do a similar thing for each fragment that needs to track the current state of the data.

Comment: i also could use the fragmentmanager to cycle trough the fragments and then update them, correct? instead of declaring a variable of a fragment(the MyFragment fragment)

Comment: That would also be fine. In that case though, you have to cast it back to your class, since `FragmentManager`'s `findFragment()` methods will return plain `Fragment`s, not `MyFragment`s.

Comment: something like: CreateRoundfragmentTab createRoundfragmentTab = (CreateRoundfragmentTab) ((FragmentPageAdapter) mAdapter)
    .getFragment("CreateRoundfragmentTab");  ?

Comment: Yes, that should work. The point is, the `Activity` has the confidence in a `Fragment`'s class signature, etc. to do the casting, while a `Fragment` can't rely on the same for the `Activity` which is why you see the interface stuff for communication in the reverse direction.

Comment: ah just noticed you using a regular method(i lack good reading), so you mean activity to fragments dont need interfaces bt methods, as activity knows who the fragments are? and the otherway arround means you need to use interfaces because the fragment doesnt know the other fragments?

Comment: You got it! Your activity can use whatever methods on your fragment you like that are visible to your activity.